# Do Temporal Tables maintain relational data?

Tags: sql, entity-framework, mariadb, temporal-tables

I'm considering using temporal tables for record keeping on a new project.  I was wondering if anyone knows if temporal tables maintain the state of relational data at the time the record was created?  I'm assuming no...

For example, if a UserTable had a FK to the Offices table, where they were a member of OfficeId 10 (San Jose), but the office has since moved to Santa Clara.  I imagine it will only maintain OfficeId 10, and not the values of what that office was at the time.

So back to my yes or no question.  Do Temporal Tables maintain relational data?

Comment: I've removed the conflicting RDBMS tags. Please [edit] your question to (re)tag the one you are really using.

Comment: There's no need for related data to be maintained if you ensure *all* relevant tables are temporal. In the example above, if the office table was temporal as well you could easily query the state of both user and office at a particular point in time. In fact, the ability to easily do so across joins is one of the big selling points of temporal tables.

Comment: I hadn't thought it all the way through, but this makes total sense.  Thank you.

Comment: Mysql does not have temporal tables, mariadb has.

Comment: Fixed tag (replaced mysql with mariadb). MariaDB started as a fork of MySQL in 2010, but both have changed a lot since then. They should now be treated as different products.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [MariaDB temporal tables](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/system-versioned-tables/) follow the SQL:2011 where the time specified applies to all system versioned tables:

```
SELECT *
FROM UserTable
JOIN OfficeTable
  USING (officeID)
FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF TIMESTAMP'2016-10-09 08:07:06';
```